# How many primary colours should my web page design have?

Tags: color-scheme

Is there any possible number of colours that I am forced not to exceed according to ux principles? 
 for example : am I able to use 3 or 4 primary colours in w web page design?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking here. There *are* only 3 primary colours, but I don't think that's what you're after. Either way, asking how many colours you can use on a site is just subjective - that depends on your visual designs, style guides etc. Every site is different, and it depends what you're wanting to convey. Without significantly more detail in this question we can't give you any concrete correct answers, so it's been temporarily closed to give you the chance to improve this question.

Comment: @JonW I think he means primary colors in terms of the website and not the color palette. Something along the lines of font guidelines (not more than x number of fonts, not more than x different font sizes, etc.)

Comment: @rk. yea, it's *Accent colors* that he refers to.

Comment: maybe my question isn't clear enough, but I intend to know if I can use more than 2 colors as a base colors for my web page, for example red header yellow slider and blue seperators green menu something like that

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While colours topic really depends on the artistic vision of the website (that's for sure) I always try to **keep this number as low as possible**, as long as it meets the **visibility and functional** needs for specific elements. What I suggest, is trying to be as close as possible to the **triadic colour scheme**, as described here: http://www.tigercolor.com/color-lab/tips/tip-01.html, with similar balance between these. Have in mind that in my work it is usually somehow pre-defined by brand guidelines - yet this is to some extent, and behind it there is the interpretation of the guidelines and (if necessary) somehow it is possible to "inject" another colour.

Speaking of functional background for colour palette, you need to remember to reserve a unique colour for clickable elements (buttons, links). Then, you need a 'neutral' color, which is used for backgrounds etc., and main content colour (fonts mainly). Sometimes you can extend it with specific colours for headers for example.

What comes after (hovers, alternate backgrounds, degraded texts like tooltips, validation messages etc.) cannot be called 'primary' (or: primary/secondary/tertiary). It extends the palette somehow, but rather as a complementary companion to it than making it more than a triad.

Btw, to plan your colours, you can use tools like this one: http://colorschemedesigner.com/ It gives you a glance at how the schemes can be constructed to make them look good and balanced. You can see there, that there are palettes from one (mono) to four colors (tetrad) suggested, yet within each of these there are also complimentary colours suggestions.

And of course, you should also refer to this board, methinks: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

That depends heavily on your design. Be careful though as you can distract the user quite a lot by to much use of to many competing colours.

There is no definitive answer to your question.